# Netbeans + Eclipse + Dart -> IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

At the moment I have 3 IDEs running at the same time, Netbeans for PHP and Python related projects (support for both are poor in Netbeans), Eclipse STS for Java/Spring/Scala projects (STS hangs when the projects get too big) and Dart IDE for Dart projects.

I'm trying out IntelliJ seeing as it has decent support for all the languages I'm working in and somehow it's a lot more stable, much faster, much more intuitive, but I can't figure out how to import multiple projects ... (that's something that just works in both Netbeans and Eclipse)

... there's a Maven Projects tab on the right, if I click the + sign it perfectly imports multiple maven projects for me and lists them in the project box, as soon as I import a non-maven project using file -> import project, all my other projects disappear and I have to re-import those projects via the Maven Projects tab. If I import a non-maven project first and then the maven projects using the Maven Projects tab on the right, I can mix one Dart project and multiple maven projects.

The suggestion out there is to import them as modules under a project, so I create an empty new project called Workspace, I select JDK 1.7 for the project SDK. Under module I click the + sign, find my project, select the pom.xml, add all the pom.xml files for that project and click ok - now I have a project with multiple modules.
Repeat for another project, import all the modules, and first project disappears.

How do I have multiple projects with their own "modules" (modules which are actually standalone projects) in IntelliJ. If projects are the eclipse equivalent of workspaces, is it possible to have multiple workspaces open? If not, how do I switch between them? (if switching is too much hassle, I'll create one mega-project and just add all projects as modules)

Comment: This looks like two questions, not one. I think it's best to ask them separately.

Comment: Ok, I'll split them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple projects open in separate IntelliJ windows. Every time you open or create a project, or open a build file such as pom.xml or build.gradle, IntelliJ asks you whether you want to open the project in the same window or a new one.

Comment: I clicked Use Same Window and don't ask me this again, shouldn't "same window" actually put the projects in the same window? Bug? If not, what happens to the other project that disappears?

Comment: No, there is no bug. Every IntelliJ window can have only one project open in it; the other project is simply closed. If you selected "Don't ask again", you can restore the prompt through Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Project Opening.

Comment: In that case I think I'll create one "project" and just import ALL the projects I work on as modules, that should give me the eclipse equivalent of having all my projects available. Thanks yole!