# Opening Dart projects in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, intellij-14

I can't seem to import dart projects, I have the dart plugin installed, have it enabled, selecting both the dart project's pubspec.yaml or build.dart seem to give me the error "Cannot import anything from _.dart / _.yaml".

If I select the root directory of the dart project and select create modules from existing sources (since it's not a maven/gradle/eclipse project), it gets picked up as a python project and there is no way to select a dart SDK.

Right clicking and clicking add framework support only gives me python related frameworks such as Django and App Engine (Python). Trying to add a project facet, there are tons of options, everything from Vaadin, to GWT, to Scala, etc, but no Dart.

The official Dart page for dart-support gives me an error 404: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/Preparing_for_Dart_Development.html

(related to [Netbeans + Eclipse + Dart -> IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879244/netbeans-eclipse-dart-intellij))

(PS, this project was created in Dart Editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` > `Open` > selecting the folder does it for me (WebStorm). I don't know what `create modules` should do.

When I open a file it asks me if I want to make it a Dart project, and I'm done.

Comment: Thanks Günter, using open actually opens it in the same window as my maven-java projects which solves my previous question of having dart and java projects open at the same time. Taking IntelliJ for a TestDrive, having to have 3 separate IDEs open is insane when IntelliJ can handle the work of all 3 :-)